# Quickest way to build a static portfolio?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Instead of going into the terminal and doing something like

`mkdir myPortfolio`

then

`touch index.html`

then

`mkdir css`

then

`touch css/style.css`

... so on and so on for  js

Is there some sort of tool to create that scaffold in one command?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I like [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com) for creating static sites, but if you're just looking for the basic files to start a website, you can just use [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com). It's quick and easy and will get you all the files you need in a few seconds which you can move to you dev directory for the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)

To install

```
npm install -g yo
```

Then create a new project with

```
yo [generator] [app-name]
```

where [generator] is the template name.

You can find a list of generators [here](http://yeoman.io/generators/)